# Opening a zendesk chat by chat id reference

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api

When a customer is viewing their basket, and they click "chat now" button, I want to be able to open a zendesk chat / web widget and connect it to specific chatId/ticketId. This is because I only want to have one chat/ticket-per-basket, such that if customer comes back after a while, and clicks "chat now" button, it should open a chat which was starter earlier, with it's history etc. available.

I can't figure out how to open a chat by specific chat reference id in javascript.

Comment: Are users signing in to the Zendesk chat widget?  And are you able to fully customize the widget?